# SQL 2 where clause

Tags: sql, where-clause

I'm trying to figure out how to complete my query. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is what I'm using to this point.

```
SELECT 
   co, queuedTime, startTime, completeTime, 
   DATEDIFF(MINUTE, queuedTime, completeTime) AS elapsedTime 
FROM 
   SJob
WHERE 
   jobClass = 'PayrollFinish' 
   AND DATEDIFF(DAY, queuedTime, GETDATE()) = 0
ORDER BY 
   queuedTime
```

The only problem is I need `queuedTime` where `job class = submitpayroll` and `completeTime` where `jobclass = payrollfinish`

I'm new to sql and just kind of thumbing my way through.

Comment: Can you give an example of sample data and expected results?

Comment: Can you also give the schema of `SJob`? How does the data relate between different records in `SJob`. In other words, does `co` reference the same row/entity, but just with different `jobClass`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you query would look like this?

```
SELECT 
    co, 
    queuedTime, 
    startTime, 
    completeTime, 
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, queuedTime, completeTime) AS elapsedTime 
FROM 
    SJob
WHERE 
    jobClass = 'PayrollFinish' AND 
    DATEDIFF(DAY,queuedTime,GETDATE())=0 
    and jobClass = 'submitpayroll' AND jobclass = 'payrollfinish'
ORDER BY 
    queuedTime
```

Comment: `jobClass` can't be both `SubmitPayroll` and `PayrollFinish`. No records will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a stab at it, since I assume you want the data from two different records.

```
SELECT 
    js.co, 
    js.queuedTime, 
    js.startTime, 
    je.completeTime, 
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, js.queuedTime, je.completeTime) AS elapsedTime 
FROM 
    SJob js
    JOIN SJob je ON js.co = je.co -- Assuming this is the joining column
    JOIN (SELECT 
            CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 101) AS DATETIME) StartDate, 
            CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE() + 1, 101) AS DATETIME) EndDate) AS date 
        ON ((js.queuedTime >= date.StartDate AND js.queuedTime < date.endDate) OR
            (je.queuedTime >= date.StartDate AND je.queuedTime < date.endDate))
WHERE 
    js.jobClass = 'SubmitPayroll' AND
    je.jobClass = 'PayrollFinish'
ORDER BY 
    js.queuedTime
```

First, since they seem to be two separate records, you need to hit the table twice (once for the `SubmitPayroll`, and the other for the `PayrollFinish` records. Since I have no idea what your schema looks like, I took a shot as to which column joins them up.

Second, I'm not sure whether you want either job to have been started or finished within that particular day, since the `SubmitPayroll` and `PayrollFinish` records are different.

Third, if you want to return all Submit records whether they having a matching Finish record or not, just convert the `JOIN SJob je` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and you'll have what you need (though you'd also need an `ISNULL` in the `DATEDIFF` for the `je.completeTime`.

Again, this is a shot in the dark without some more information regarding your schema/data, but hopefully this gets you closer to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one of the times, then this should do the trick.

```
SELECT  co, 
        CASE time
            WHEN jobClass = 'SubmitPayroll' THEN queuedTime
            WHEN jobClass = 'PayrollFinish' AND DATEDIFF(DAY, queuedTime, GETDATE()) = 0 THEN completeTime
            ELSE 'N/A'
        END,
        startTime,
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE, queuedTime, completeTime) AS elapsedTime 
  FROM SJob
 ORDER BY queuedTime
```